# scala error "pattern type is incompatible with expected type"

Tags: scala

I am working my way through the "Functional Programming in Scala" book. Chapter 5.2 starts with the following code:

```
sealed trait Stream[+A]
case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

object Stream {
  def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
    lazy val head = hd
    lazy val tail = tl
    Cons(() => head, () => tail)
  }

  def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

  def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

}
```

Then the following definition is given:

```
  def headOption: Option[A] = this match {
      case Empty => None
      case Cons(h, t) => Some(h())
    }
```

I assume it should be part of the companion object. To not get a compile error immediately I add "headOption[A]". But when I include the result into "object Stream" I am getting the error "pattern type is incompatible with expected type; found : myPackage.Empty.type required: myPackage.Stream.type" with "Empty" underlined.

I am a little lost here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be part of the `trait Stream[+A]`.

Here `this` refers to the `Stream` (trait Stream not companion object). `Stream` can be `Empty` or it can be `Cons`. So pattern matching on `this` makes sense.

`headOption` gives first element of the stream if available.

```
    case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]

    case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

    sealed trait Stream[+A] {
      def headOption: Option[A] = this match {
        case Empty => None
        case Cons(h, t) => Some(h())
      }
    }



    object Stream {

      def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
        lazy val head = hd
        lazy val tail = tl
        Cons(() => head, () => tail)
      }

      def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

      def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
        if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))


    }
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]

case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

sealed trait Stream[+A] {

  def headOption: Option[A] = this match {
    case Empty => None
    case Cons(h, t) => Some(h())
  }

}

object Stream {

  def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
    lazy val head = hd
    lazy val tail = tl
    Cons(() => head, () => tail)
  }

  def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

  def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object Empty
defined class Cons
defined trait Stream
defined object Stream

scala> Stream.cons(1, Empty).headOption
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! After thinking about it some more I understand why it must be this way.